# VBA copy data to Copy Data To New Workbook Based On Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks - Data file (Sheet: Andhra Pradesh) & Invoice file (new invoice to be added after the last invoice).

I want to use the pivot table in data workbook to create invoice in the invoice workbook. 1 PO number per 1 Invoice.

For example: row 9B DO3566521 will be copied into a new Invoice 300 in Invoice workbook with the following information:

- Order Closed Date (A9) to be copied into  I16
- PO Number DO666 (B9) to be copied into  B31,
- Order ID 1234 (C9) to be copied into  A34,
- Spec Name - 3 items (E9:E11) to be copied into  B34:B36,
- Invoice Qty (F9:F11) to be copied into  G34:G36,
- Invoice Amount (G9:G11) to be copied into  I34:36
- PO Number DO667 (B12) should be copied into another new Invoice 301 (a new worksheet 301 to be added in Invoice workbook)...

I can get the Invoice Workbook to add/copy a new worksheet but I'm having trouble copying over the data & writing the loop function. how to create a new invoice if it's a different PO? Any help would be much appreciated!!

BTW, I also have a macro (`Sub Get_Spelling()`) to convert numbers into words in invoice worksheet (A55). Just wondering how can I join them together so it gets updated automatically when invoice is created.

Data workbook - Sheet Name: Andhra Pradesh

```
A9                B9        C9         D9        E9        F9    G9
Order Closed Date PO Number Order ID  Item Index Spec Name Qty  Invoice Amt
15/09/11          DO666     1234        1        A         10    $100
                                        2        B         20    $200 
                                        3        C         30    $300
                  DO667     567         1        L         40    $100 
                                        2        K         50    $200
```

Invoice workbook - Sheet name: Invoice Number (e.g Inv 300)

```
B31
PO Number DO666
A34        B34           G34       I34
Order ID   Spec Name     Qty      Invoice Amt
1234        A            10        $100
            B            20        $200
            C            30        $300

Invoice 301
B31
PO Number: DO667
```

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Invoice()
Dim oldsheet As Worksheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim oldnumber As Integer
Dim newnumber As Integer
Dim databook As Workbook
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim invbook As Workbook
Set databook = ActiveWorkbook
Set invbook = ActiveWorkbook

Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\New folder\AP VAT Inv 201 -.xls")
'Set invbook = ActiveWorkbook

oldnumber = ActiveSheet.Name
newnumber = oldnumber + 1

ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set newSheet = ActiveSheet

ActiveSheet.Name = newnumber
ActiveSheet.Range("I15").Value = newnumber
ActiveSheet.Range("I16") = databook.Sheets("Andhra Pradesh").Range("A9")

MsgBox "Invoices have been created successfully"
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of confused by some of what you're asking but something along the lines of the following should work. Just adapt it to your needs.

```
Sub Main()
Dim wkbook As Workbook
Set wkbook = Workbooks.Add

If Len(dir( ***Your Directory Path *****, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir ***Your Directory Path *****
End If

With wkbook
    .Title = "Workbook Title"
    .Subject = "Workbook Subject"
    .SaveAs FileName:= ***Your Directory Path *****\"Workbook Title.xls"
End With

With wkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
.Range("I16") = **Your Original Worksheet**.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
'repeat for all values
end with

wkbook.save
wkbook.close
end sub
```

If I were you I'd pass your values in the original workbook to a variant array and then read through them with a for loop. As in..

```
dim myValues as Variant
dim I as Integer

myValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9:G11").Value

for I = LBound(myValues) to Ubound(myvalues)
'do work here (See the with wkbook statement above)
next I
```

That should get you started.